# GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT vs GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX

Tags: debian, grub2, grub

What is the difference between these two options in `/boot/default/grub`

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

From the [wiki on Grub Setup](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Setup)

- `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` Entries on this line are added to the end of the 'linux' command line (GRUB legacy's "kernel" line) for **both normal and recovery modes.** It is used to pass options to the kernel.
- `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` This line imports any entries to the end of the 'linux' line (GRUB legacy's "kernel" line). The entries are appended to the end of the **normal mode only.** To view a black screen with boot processes displayed in text, remove "quiet splash". To see the grub splash image plus a condensed text output, use "splash".

They're pretty horrendously named for having to do predominately with the modes in which they apply and not having anything to do with `DEFAULT`.

Comment: well i guess the "default" would suggests default (normal) boot, as opposed to recovery mode, but I completely agree! espetially considering how long they made that parameter title, they couldve made it more clear

Comment: Horrendously named indeed.

Comment: Thank god I looked it up before assuming what they are!

Comment: I added lines `# normal and rescue mode` and `# normal mode only` because I'll totally forget this in a year.  Thanks!

Comment: So what variable adds lines only to recovery modes?

Comment: Oh, https://mail.gnu.org/archive/html/grub-devel/2021-09/msg00086.html