# Which GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_* for recovery mode only?

Tags: linux, boot, grub2, system-recovery

As we see in
[GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT vs GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/440961/grub-cmdline-linux-default-vs-grub-cmdline-linux), [etc.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/575651/what-is-the-difference-between-grub-cmdline-linux-and-grub-cmdline-linux-default),

- GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX is for both normal **and** recovery modes.
- GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT is for **normal** mode **only**.

So, which

- GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_???, if any, is for **recovery** mode **only**?

Sure, GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_RECOVERY. Alas, not accessible: https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?64385

Sure, "just add it on yourself to the kernel command line each reboot, by hand!" But that is painful. Yes, I am talking about grub2 across all platforms.